# java3d eclipse problem on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-3d

Part of the responsibilities of my job is maintaining an old java application that was developed by my predecessor. I am a php developer with minimal java skills. The java application is developed with java3d and I work in eclipse on my macbook pro.  I know that the version of java3d on my mac (and all other macs out there) is 1.3 which is very old. My application needs at least 1.5.  I run "jar" on the command line to create a jar with all the png's and class files, then I sign the jar, and then I put it on my website and deliver it with jnlp.  It works perfectly on windows.  It will *load* on macs, but when I try to select a point it crashes with a NoSuchMethodError error.  Selecting a point requires javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup.pickAll which wasn't in java 1.3 which came stock on my mac.  I have two questions/requests:

(1) How do I configure eclipse to make my application work locally?

(2) How do I bundle my jar such that my online viewers with macs don't have any problems?

I have tried many things to get this to work.  I have moved a bunch of the jars in /System/Library/Java/Extensions (that is where the java 1.3 jars are).  I have downloaded a fresh java3d which contains a few jars.  I put them in ~/Library/Jars/.  And I put those jars in the Java Build Path:

http://archive.cyark.org/temp/screenshot.png

I've spent a lot of time on this issue and I've done all the things that other posts have mentioned. What is wrong with my environment?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the Java3D 1.5 JARS for MacOSX from here?:
http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html

In the Mac OS binary, there are instructions on how to install and configure Java3D for an OSX system

Have you tried following those steps?

My guess is that the 1.3 JARS are still on your classpath somewhere and are being loaded before the new 1.5 jars.  Try searching your system for all possible instances of the JARS would be a good start.

Comment: I have replaced all 1.3 jars with the 1.5 jars on my user account and in the /System folder. I also have included in my build path in my project in eclipse all the new jars (j3dcore, j3dutils, vecmath, jnlp, gluegen-rt, and jogl). Any other ideas?